# How can I search a list of classes for a specific property of the class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class called `Product` which has two properties.

```
class Product {
  final String productName;
  final int expiryTime;

  Product(this.productName, this.expiryTime);
}
```

I then made a list of `Product`s like below:

```
List<Product> allProducts = [
  Product('Apple', 5),
  Product('Banana', 3),
  Product('Pear', 7),
];
```

I want to search this list to check if a product is in it.  For example, if I check if 'Apple' is in the list `allProducts`, it should be `true`.

For other lists I have used `list.contains()` but I cannot see how to use it for this type of list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**any** returns `true` if the given condition is met in dart list. Hope it helps

```dart
var found = allProducts.any((e) => e.productName == "Apple");
print(found);
```

Comment: Zain, can you have a look at my question as well? I am getting into the way of things with Flutter and cannot get what I am doing wrong now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61711139/mapeventtostate-triggers-one-time-only 
I would appreciate any hints on the code

Comment: Sure let me check

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
  allProducts.forEach((res){
    if(res.productName == "Apple"){
      print("True");
    }
  });
```

Iterate inside the list, then check if `res.productName` is equal to `Apple`